# OOP File Read Problems

Tags: java, file, oop, io

I am having some issues reading in the first line of data in java using OOP. This works without OOP here:

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); // sets up scanner
    System.out.print("Enter file name: "); //user provides file name and location
    String userFile = in.nextLine(); // accepts input from user
    File file = new File(userFile); //uses the file method to import the data
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file); // uses scanner to read the data
    String fileContents = inputFile.nextLine();
    System.out.print(fileContents);
```

However I can't' get this to work in the class file because The method nextLine() is undefined for the type String, even though I literally just used that above.

```
    public String Out(String userIn)
{
    String nOfStudentsIndex = userIn.nextLine();
```

Also why can't I pass in the file to the other class file this way?

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); // sets up scanner
    System.out.print("Enter file name: "); //user provides file name and location
    String userFile = in.nextLine(); // accepts input from user
    File file = new File(userFile); //uses the file method to import the data
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file); // uses scanner to read the data
    System.out.println(inputFile.Out());
```

Comment: `String` has no `nextLine()`, `Scanner` does.

Answer (score 3):

Why not pass in the Scanner object where it's needed?  e.g.,

```
// pass in Scanner, not String
public String Out(Scanner userIn) {
    String nOfStudentsIndex = userIn.nextLine();
```

Just be sure not to close the Scanner that uses `System.in` until your program is definitely done using it.

Also, this won't work:

```
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file); // uses scanner to read the data
System.out.println(inputFile.Out());
```

as Scanner doesn't have an `Out()` method. You can only use the methods that are available to the class, as per the Scanner API.

You could parse through the file using your Scanner, printing out each line as it comes using a while loop

```
Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(file); // uses scanner to read the data
while (fileScan.hasNextLine()) {
    System.out.println(fileScan.nextLine();
}
fileScan.close();
```

Comment: I need to pass fileScan into another class file to have calculations done on it. The process above simply prints it out until there are no lines left.

Comment: @frillybob: Then pass it in elsewhere. But my guess is that more than the Scanner, you will need the **contents** of the file. So perhaps you wish to extract it into an `ArrayList<String>` or a StringBuilder, and then pass *that* where needed.